# fullpage.js - normal scrolling for sections larger than the viewport

Tags: javascript, fullpage.js

For fullpage.js, is there a way to allow normal scrolling (such as on a regular webpage) for larger sections (larger than the size of the viewport height)?

Comment: Maybe you need to attach more info about the problem for total understand your question

Answer (score 1):

The most you can do is make use of the `scrollOverflow` option of fullpage.js as [in this example](https://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/examples/scrolling.html).